# For which crime was Jogendra arrested?

Tags: plot-explanation, nene-raju-nene-mantri

The movie *[Nene Raju Nene Mantri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nene_Raju_Nene_Mantri)* is a 2017 Telugu political thriller. It starts with the scene where Jogendra ([Rana Daggubati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rana_Daggubati)) is arrested and taken to Central prison to get hanged. It is known that he is being hanged for a murder he did in his life but it's not clear which murder it is. He had killed many people (Sarpanch, MLA and many other) on his way to the position of Chief Minister of state. However, in the film, it is not shown that he is guilty of any murder or police arresting him for a charge of murder. People  and media were shocked when they learnt about the murders when Jogendra confesses. None of his killings were proved until he himself confessed in the interview.

So, my question is for which murder is Jogendra arrested and sentenced to death? Is it mentioned anywhere in the film? Did I miss this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He gets arrested not for the murders he does in the past (no one knows about them until he confesses) but for blowing up the assembly house filled up with the MLAs.

I think you missed this scene: 
*(right after he wins the elections, he goes into the assembly house, asks if anyone repents moving and are willing to come back into his party, comes outside and detonates a bomb set up in the assembly building)*

They shift from his party to the opposition party after winning the elections using Jogendras party and he considers that cheating the people and him. So he blows them up and end up in jail for mass murder.

PS. Adding after your comment.

Coming to "None of his killings were proved until he himself confessed in the interview." is not a confirmed fact. He is to be hanged later that day and his last wish was to let the public know about his life (and probably the entire story of why he had to kill the 250 MLAs). It was not necessary that the public already knew of his wrongdoings.

I also think he could have been outed by anyone from the police to family members of the people he killed. Or he may have surrendered owing to his 'martyr' behavior in the last few scenes.

Also the Jailer being surprised could have been bad story writing maybe or that he is not well informed? 
Because the Jailer says "You want to make such a scene for a murderer?"
and "Who is he to telecast his story? Alluri SRR or Subash Chandra Bose?"

Comment: That's what I thought too but in the end, Jailer Jaiprakash and others were surprised and Jailer says "You killed 250 politicians?" and salutes him for doing so. So, they knew about the mass murder? Was it for blasting assembly?

Comment: i kinds sat and watched the whole movie again but as you said its nowhere clearly stated as to why he is arrested. BUt the last thing he does and talks about is the mass murder after which the story completely comes to the present. So logically it should be the mass murder for which he is to be hanged. I'm assuming it was bad story writing coming to the Jailers dialogue.